# How to get my localhost wordpress to my domain with cpanel?

Tags: localhost

I've tried multiple online guides to try and get my localhost wordpress site onto the domain but i can't get it right.

I have CPanel open and a domain set up and i can see Softaculous has a WordPress installer. Should i install that first?

I am so confused.

CPanel has a File Manager section so is that where i import my theme files etc?

Thank you

Comment: Your site is in your localhost ?

Comment: You have to create a database in cpanel and upload database in cpanel database and change wp-config.php file database details for file manager section

Comment: maybe you should describe what is it that you "can not get right"

Answer (score 0):

The Answer mentioned by Gautam Jha is perfect, 
But if you fear or don't like that method and rather would want to go by the copy paste method then

(A) Do not ( Don't) use Softaculous for below method

(1) the most important thing is to export your DB from your localhost's PhpMyAdmin and import in your Cpanel's PhpMyAdmin
(1.1) Here you need to make sure the prefix i.e. wp_ need to carry forward with compliance with the prefix provided by your shared hosting. 
(1.2) For that before importing the sql file, you need to accordingly bulk replace the prefix in a .sql file using Sublime text editor(preferably) 
(1.3) Also bulk replace the locahost url with live domain URL

Once you have successfully got the DB copied at your CPanel then simply

(2) Copy the root folder from localhost to your CPanel (assuming that you know what to copy paste where and how, ComeOn this is common sense, play a bit if you get struck here) (2.2) Open the wp_config file and check the DB table name for mismatch if any.

(3) Now open you site in browser it must show the site properly if the bulk replace was done perfectly in the previous step.

I'm assuming that you know the hidden basic steps which a developer gathers with his experience.

Comment: i am Gautam Jha, can you correct it

Comment: haha, Corrected! :)